# Showing alertview as soon as location service is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I'm making an iOS app which requires location services enabled. So as soon as my app is installed, it asks users to allow location service. Apparently, a lot of users press "Don't allow" and ended up having not working my iOS app.

In my app, I input below lines of code:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
            self.locationAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Location Services Permission Needed", message: "Location service needs to be turned on to use Peek! Please press setting button below and turn the service on!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Settings")
            locationAlert.show()
      }
    }

    extension ViewController: UIAlertViewDelegate {
        func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
            alertView.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(buttonIndex, animated: true)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the alertview only shows up when you reopen the app. I want this alertview to show up as soon as users press "Don't allow location service" when they installed the app.

Is there a way to make this action happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use delegate method of [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

This method tells you if the status of location authorization has *changed*.

**Example:**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .Denied:
        // Changed status to denied
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

***Note:*** Remember to set delegate of CLLocationManager to self! Also better to check if that alert view isn't already being presented to avoid multi alerts.